# Facebook getSignedRequest not working

Tags: php, facebook, api, request

my code:

```
<?
session_start();
include('facebook.php');

$config['appid' ] = "xxxxxxxxx";
$config['secret'] = "xxxxxxxxx";

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $config['appid'],
    'secret' => $config['secret'],
    'cookie' => true
));

$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if($signedRequest['page']['liked'] == 1) echo "LIKED";
?>
```

Code not working in new created app, but it work in older application.

I need help. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for the answer

Comment: Could you please give more information?  it would be useful if you give us the response you get (try printing the $signedRequest; also what does your app prints to screen or logs?).

Answer (score 0):

Can you do var_dump($signedRequest);

You Server has SSL certificat ?
Test your application after you disable https of Facebook -> https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&edited=browsing